# how can I brute-force 5 characters in python to crack sha256 with multiprocess or multithread?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, brute-force, multiprocess

everything is fine with 4 characters and Pool.map, it runs in about 46s

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
from hashlib import sha256
from string import printable
from itertools import product, count

charset = printable[:-6]
chars = [c.encode() for c in charset]

def e(i):
    # sha256(W1n^r)  = 705c098135f1d15e28157c6424b17a7803ccbb6a218baaa312845de7b43303fe
    if sha256(i).hexdigest() == "705c098135f1d15e28157c6424b17a7803ccbb6a218baaa312845de7b43303fe":
        print(f"FOUND msg: {i}")
        return f"FOUND msg: {i}"

def g():
    for length in count(start=1):
        if length == 5:
            break
        for pwd in product(chars, repeat=length):
            yield b''.join(pwd)
    print("generator done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    for res in tqdm(p.map(e, g())):
        if res is not None:
            break
```

However, when the number of characters increased to 5, the generator was overloaded and my computer crashed.
I looked up some solutions that suggested using imap but it took up to 2 hours??? while regular brute-force only takes about 1m33s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cz1K.png

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
from hashlib import sha256
from string import printable
from itertools import product, count

charset = printable[:-6]
chars = [c.encode() for c in charset]

arr = []
def e(i):
    if sha256(i).hexdigest() == "705c098135f1d15e28157c6424b17a7803ccbb6a218baaa312845de7b43303fe": # W1n^r
        print(f"FOUND msg: {i}")
        return True

def g():
    for length in count(start=1):
        if length == 5:
            break
        for pwd in product(chars, repeat=length):
            yield b''.join(pwd)
    print("generator done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    for i in tqdm(g(), total=78914410):
        res = e(i)
        if res is not None:
            break
```

How should I handle the generator so that I can combine it with mutilprocess to brute-force 5 characters?

Comment: Your computer crashed?

Comment: I mean my computer lags and I have to reboot

Comment: Can you show the code for "regular brute-force"?

Comment: yep, i was updated

Comment: Your "brute-force" code runs in <42s on Apple Silicon M2. However, it still doesn't crack the password

Comment: sure, my code is running with 4 chars, but result is `W1n^r` 5 chars, i want check speed when run 100% (all testcase), you can try with 5 chars but it very slow, regular brute-force cant run complete cuz generator killed

Comment: if use 5 for loops can be completed in 2 hours but i want improve speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing would be superior to multithreading as the core functionality is CPU-bound.

You can use queues for communication between the main (parent) process and the subprocesses.

The following code runs for just over 12 minutes on my system. Results will vary according to platform and variations on number of subprocesses, batch size and password length.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from string import printable
from itertools import product, cycle
from hashlib import sha256
from queue import Empty
from time import perf_counter


PROCS = 7 # one less that CPU count
MAXLEN = 5
DIGEST = "705c098135f1d15e28157c6424b17a7803ccbb6a218baaa312845de7b43303fe"
BATCH = 10_000 # empirically determined to be a fairly good batch size

# check a batch of passwords
def process(qsend, qres):
    while batch := qsend.get():
        for v in map(str.encode, batch):
            if sha256(v).hexdigest() == DIGEST:
                qres.put(v)
                break

# generate passwords
def genpwd():
    for length in range(1, MAXLEN + 1):
        for pwd in product(printable[:-6], repeat=length):
            yield "".join(pwd)


def main():
    qres = Queue() # response queue
    # start PROCS processes each with a discrete input queue
    # each proc uses the same response queue
    procs = []
    for queue in (queues := [Queue() for _ in range(PROCS)]):
        (proc := Process(target=process, args=(queue, qres))).start()
        procs.append(proc)

    batch = []
    qc = cycle(queues)
    solution = None

    for pwd in genpwd():
        batch.append(pwd)
        if len(batch) == BATCH:
            # send batch to the next queue in the cycle
            next(qc).put(batch)
            batch = []
            # occasional check for a response
            try:
                solution = qres.get(block=False)
                break
            except Empty:
                pass

    # if there's no solution (yet) make sure anything left over in the batch list is submitted
    if not solution:
        next(qc).put(batch)
    
    # tells each process to stop
    for queue in queues:
        queue.put(None)

    # wait for all subprocesses to end
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # if there was no solution, check the response queue once more
    # ...because there could be subprocesses still running when the main loop ended (generator exhausted)
    if not solution:
        try:
            solution = qres.get(block=False)
        except Empty:
            pass

    if solution:
        print(f"Solution = {solution}")
    else:
        print("No solution found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = perf_counter()
    main()
    end = perf_counter()
    duration = int(end - start)
    print(f"Duration={duration}s")
```

**Output:**

```
Solution = W1n^r
Duration=730s
```

Comment: How long does their second program run on your system?

Comment: @KellyBundy See comment on original question

Comment: Ah, yes. So it'd probably take ~41 minutes to find it (when allowing length 5). I wonder why yours is so much faster than their multiprocess attempt. I guess mostly the hatching. But it's still a lot of communication overhead, so I suspect it could be even better...

Comment: @KellyBundy I tried to reduce communication by batching and found that even with batches of 25,000 it didn't make much difference to the overall duration. There's almost certainly a better way to do this but I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Can you try mine, with `mp.Pool(8)`? It tries to reduce the communication a lot. I don't have a machine with many cores, can't test very meaningfully myself.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `p.map(e, g())):` with `p.imap(e, g(), 10000)`. The `imap` avoids memory exhaustion and the chunk size 10000 (default is 1) avoids a lot of communication overhead, similar to [Codist's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77395068). Made it ~125 times faster in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't micro-manage the processes.

You give them microscopic tasks like `check the single password "b3.cw"`, which involves a large communication overhead for transmitting each password and the result. Instead, give them tasks like `check all passwords that start with "b3" and have 3 more chars`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
from hashlib import sha256
from string import printable
from itertools import product, count

charset = printable[:-6]
chars = [c.encode() for c in charset]

def e(args):
    prefix, suffix_length = args
    for suffix in product(chars, repeat=suffix_length):
        pwd = prefix + suffix
        i = b''.join(pwd)
        if sha256(i).hexdigest() == "705c098135f1d15e28157c6424b17a7803ccbb6a218baaa312845de7b43303fe":
            print(f"FOUND msg: {i}")
            return f"FOUND msg: {i}"

def g():
    for length in count(start=1):
        if length == 6:
            break
        prefix_length = length // 2
        suffix_length = length - prefix_length
        for prefix in product(chars, repeat=prefix_length):
            yield prefix, suffix_length
    print("generator done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    for res in tqdm(p.imap(e, g())):
        if res is not None:
            break
```